# Cant open twice an iframe

Tags: java, iframe, jpanel, panel, actionlistener

I have tried to make an app that it will open a menu with buttons [ insert search for example]. When a click a button an other iframe will be open for each button. But when it comes to click second time the button insert, iframe was crashed.
Even if after the insert, I click search, the iframe was crashed again.

The main frame:

```
   public Exercise(){
        frame1= new JFrame(); 
        frame1.setSize(400, 100);

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setVisible(true);

        in= new JButton("insert");
        in.setSize(50, 10);
        in.setLocation(100, 100);
        panel1.add(in);

        s = new JButton("search");
        s.setSize(50, 10);
        s.setLocation(200, 200);
        panel1.add(s);
        s.setVisible(true);

        frame1.add(panel1);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        in.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

          @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                   insert();
        });
        s.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

          @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                   search()
        });

        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }
```

The search function:

```
public void search(){ 
frame3= new JFrame();
frame3.setSize(300, 300);
panel3 = new JPanel();
panel3.setLayout( null );
    /* and other textfields and labels */
JButton go= new JButton("go");                    
go.setSize(100, 100);
go.setBounds(10, 200,200,20);
panel3.add(go);

frame3.add(panel3);
frame3.setVisible(true);
go.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  ////// .... ////
    frame3.setVisible(false)
  /* I have already tried:
   frame3.dispose().
   frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);*/
});
}
```

The insert function

```
public void insert(){ 
frame2= new JFrame();
frame2.setSize(300, 300);
panel2 = new JPanel();
panel2.setLayout( null );
/* and other labels and textfields */

JButton save= new JButton("save");                    
save.setSize(100, 100);
save.setBounds(10, 200,200,20);
panel2.add(save);

frame2.add(panel2);
frame2.setVisible(true);
save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
  ////// .... ////
    frame2.setVisible(false)

});
}
```

What can I do?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to create a new frame each time a button is pressed: you do that with search() and insert(). So the bset you can do is keep one frame for frame 2, one for frame 3 etc and make them visible/invisible as needed.

That is create the frames outside the functions search() insert() - maybe in the constructor.